# Programmatically determine the html background color

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, components

Is there a way to determine the background color used in the html, from inside an angular component?
I am writing an angular component that's inside one of the many feature modules used where I need to know the background color used by the page, and I would like to determine dynamically the background color utilized. The webpage has multiple tabs, and this component can appear in any tab

Comment: try [windows.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). NOTE: I'm not prety sure if it's possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
getComputedStyle(document?.querySelector?.("body") as Element).backgroundColor
```

Comment: Pourush, I would like to determine the current background color, not change

Comment: what do you mean? explain me the different please

Comment: I am new to angular/web development and all; I am trying to determine what is the background color used by the page. Is there someting like  document.querySelector.getAtrribute?

Comment: of course, try something like that `console.log(document?.querySelector?.("body")?.style?.backgroundColor);` and you'll get the body bg color

Comment: that returns empty

Comment: I changed my answer - check it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249590/discussion-between-eli-porush-and-user6386155).